# How do I display a column from SQlite in HTML?

Tags: javascript, java, html, sqlite, playframework

I have made a SQLite database with some users for a small website I'm working on, and I would like to display all of those usernames on my website. I use Java, JavaScript, HTML and SQL.

The overview of my SQLite:

```
Table name: users
Column names: username, password
My guess on the SQL code: SELECT username FROM users
```

Here is the solution!

```
public ArrayList<String> selectUsernames() {
    public ArrayList<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT username FROM users";

        try {
        java.sql.Connection conn = connect();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            username = rs.getString("username");
            System.out.println(rs.getString("username"));
            usernameList.add(username);

        }
        for(int i = 0; i < usernameList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(usernameList.get(i));
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error line 43");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return usernameList;

}
```

Then in the HTML i added this Scala line

```
@(users: List[String])
```

Now if i type `@users` it will print out all usernames! Now im trying to make a scala for loop.

Comment: Your SQL is correct. You might want to provide more information about what libraries your using for things such as database access and HTML generation. Also, are you generating a populated HTML page to send to the browser, or are you using AJAX to request the data and then populating the page using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You dont use SQL in JavaScript because its client-sided and you wont give the website user your SQL Password ...

How did you implement Java?
You should use PHP

Comment: I'm an intern at a company in Sweden, and they gave me a mini version of their website. For example: The login sends the input username and password to a JavaScript that sends it to a Java file which uses FormFactory (no idea what that does tbh) that sends it to another java file that checks with the sqlite database if the username and passwords match.

Comment: Websockets I guess? PHP would be still the best solution... when you send the data from JavaScript to Java its insecure

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems you are not sure what to do next after creating a db; first an overview and then some questions you need to find answer(s) for:

1. **Model**: You need to write you models' code to talk to the database, they need to be written at `app/models` folder.
2. **Controller**: You then need to write a method call to your code you wrote in the first step within `/models` folder to get the data. Then you pass it on to the views. These codes will be within the `app/controllers` folder
3. **Views**: Views code, that are `*.scala.html` files within `app/views` folder view the code.

So now you are familiar with an overview of the model/view/controller (MVC).

What is next?

1. You need to learn how to populate your database.
2. How to call a database, in your models.
3. How to import models' classes into your controller.
4. How to create a response into views.
5. How to use the twirl template engine to write scala/html in your views.

The above questions should set you on a journey on seek and learn different parts of the Playframework. Good luck!